# *ngIf for the existing property of the obj does not work

Tags: html, angular, typescript

The line `ngIf="!row.widgetAccess.isvalid"` does not work although I have the `isValid` property for my `widgetAccess` obj. Would you please help? I need to control showing of the `mat-icon` by `ngIf="!row.widgetAccess.isvalid"`. Thanks

TS:

```js
makeRowData(): void {
  this.rowData = [];
  this.dynamicGroups.forEach(group => {
    this.rowData.push({
      dynamicGroup: group,
      widgetAccess: {
        dynamicGroupUID: group.uId,
        hasAccess: false,
        widgets: [],
        isValid: true,
      } as WidgetAccess
    });
  });

  this.dashboardConfiguration.widgets?.forEach(widget => {
    this.rowData.forEach(widgetGroup => {
      if (widgetGroup.dynamicGroup.uId === widget.dynamicGroupUID) {
        widgetGroup.widgetAccess = widget;
      }
      if (widget.widgets.filter(wA => wA.isValid = false).length > 0) {
        widget.isValid = false;
      };
    });
  });
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let row of rowData" class="dynamic-group">
    <div class="tw-w-3 tw-float-right -tw-mt-3" *ngIf="!row.widgetAccess.isvalid">
      <mat-icon svgIcon="alerts_outlined" class="tw-max-w-3" aria- hidden="true">
      </mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-edit-nounderline" (click)="edit(row.widgetAccess)">

      <span matTooltipClass="" [matTooltipPosition]="'after'" class="btn-
edit" matTooltip="{{getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)}}">
        <u>{{'EditTitle' | translate}}</u> </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When/Where you are calling `makeRowData()` function?

Comment: And  ` widgetGroup.widgetAccess = widget;` line may be merge the isValid value to be false right?